# Linkedin share doesn't show any info. Just the main URL of our website

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

If I try to share an article from our website: http://www.acquisitie.org/ to Linkedin, it only shows the main URL from our website. So not the url from the specific article,also no data, image etc. This happens while using the share button and also posting a URL to status update.

This is a Wordpress website and the sharing issue started last month.

What I've tried:
- Disable different plugins that could cause Open Graph conflicts
- Checked Facebook Open Graph debugger for big errors
- Tried different social sharing plugins
- Searching like crazy for a solution

Now unfortunately I'm not the only one with Linkedin share issues as you can see here: http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/attempts-share-url-linkedin-ignore-open-graph-tags, but maybe someone here can help me out. This is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using better_wp_security on your website?

I had the same problem, and in the .htaccess file, there was a line that was blocking the content from showing in LinkedIn.

For me, at the bottom of the #Abuse Agent Blocking section in the .htaccess file, there is the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

I removed that particular one, and my blog post content shows up correctly in LinkedIn.

Definitely want to make a backup of .htaccess if you're modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I lied - that wasn't the complete solution.

It gave the initial image, but when I shared the content the image went away again.

I removed all of the RewiteRule options from .htaccess and it's working.

Now I just need to figure out which specific one is causing the problem, but that's definitely where it is.

Answer (score 0):

for me its  better_wp_security, I disabled it and now its sorted.  Jetpack has security built in so that will do the job nicely

Answer (score 0):

> So not the url from the specific article,also no data, image etc....

So, I looked at your site's code, the current 2020 version and a [2013 version supplied by Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130722150203/http://www.acquisitie.org/).  Both of them ***do not contain any `og:image` tag.***  You need to have an `og:image` tag to specify the image you want to be used when sharing.  You do have *some* `og:` tags, ***but not the `og:image` one.***  Look:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="nl_NL"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Acquisitie » Meer Klanten, Meer Orders, Meer Omzet"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Verkoop meer!"/>
...
(no og:image tag)
```

Add one, as indicated by the [Official LinkedIn Shareable Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).  Like this...

```
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
```

Still uncertain that you're doing it incorrectly?  Try the URL you are trying to share (i.e., `yoursite.com/pageToShareOnLinkedin`) here: [**Official LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).  That should be able to tell you exactly why an image isn't being selected.  Of course, for now it will indicate the absence of `og:` tag.